# How to prove that $2^{20}$ is not divisible by $9$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove that $2^{20}$ is not divisible by $9$?

do i start with $2^{30}=9k$?

Comment: Let's see $2^{20} = 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2$, $20$ times and $9 = 3\cdot 3$. Now, how do we give an argument that $9$ can't divide $2^{20}$?

Comment: @Atticus because 3 cannot divide 2?

Comment: Well, to be fair $2^{20}$ is quite small, so if you really have no idea how to do it using modular arithmetic, do $2^{20}=1024\cdot 1024$ in your head (or use long multiplication), then check if the [sum of it's digits is divisible by $9$](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~lee/as100fa02/divide.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2^3≡-1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$$
$$(2^3)^6≡(-1)^6\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$$
$$2^{18}≡1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$$
$$2^2×2^{18}≡2^2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$$
$$2^{20}≡4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$$

As you see the reminder is not $0$, so the result follows.

Comment: The answers to this question are under attack of a serial downvoter.

Comment: yes I guess, I think there should be more than one of them , and it seems that they have no idea about the question itself!

Answer (score 1):

By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), $2$ is the only prime factor of $2^{20}$, while $3$ is the only prime factor of $9$. So $9|2^{20}$ would imply $3|2^{20}$ and the contradiction $3=2$.

Comment: The answers to this question are under attack of a serial downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

If $2^{20}$ is divisible by $9$ then of course also by prime $3$ simply because $9$ is divisible by $3$.

However, characteristic for prime $p$ is: $$p|ab\implies p|a\text{ or }p|b$$
So $3\mid 2^{20}$ leads to $3\mid 2^{k}$ where $k<20$.

Repeating this we finally arrive at $3|2$ which is not true.

Comment: drhab. Let's not worry about downvotes.Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Induction:

Show that $2^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n\ge 2$,  is not divisible by $3$.

Base case $n=2:$ $3\not | 2^2=4$ .

Hypothesis: $3\not | 2^n$.

Step $n+1$:

$2^{n+1}=2^n 2.$

Euclid's lemma:

If $p$, prime, divides $ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Assume $3|2^{n+1}$, then

$3|2^n$ or $3|2$.

But $3\not |2^n$ by hypothesis, and $3\not |2$.

Hence $3\not | 2^{n+1}$, and we are done.

Comment: The answers to this question are under attack of a serial downvoter.

Comment: I already upvoted some time ago so unfortunately cannot repair the attack by an upvote.